# How can I store some variable in local Storage in encrypted format and later want to decrypt it?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, cordova

I am creating a phone app using JavaScript.

I want to store an array of strings in local storage in an encrypted format so that it is not readable by the normal user.

I found some libraries like `CryptoJs`. But I don't want to use any library as I am hoping it would be merely 4 or 5 lines of code which I want to write myself.

**Question**

Am I able to achieve this kind of encryption in a few lines of code?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I found some library like CryptoJs. But I don't want to use any library as I am hoping it would be merely 4 or 5 line code which I want to write myself

Comment: If it takes only 4-5 lines of code to encrypt sth. then it will be a pretty small library and you can copy-paste it into your code. If the library is bigger, it probably takes a little more effort to encrypt the data.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Move OP's clarification of the question into the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess secure storage Cordova plugin should help you achieve this out of the box.

It helps in storing sensitive info in device in encrypted format. Check out [secure storage Cordova plugin](https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage) Hope it helps.

Comment: [secure storage Cordova plugin](https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage) is a perfect solution for me. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow, will you please explain me how to accept the answer @Gandhi

Comment: @SamimAhmed Please check out this link - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers